# can't change file permission

Tags: permissions, executable, usb-drive

Whenever I create or copy few shell files to usb storage device, then I am not able to make them executable.

If I create test.sh, it's default file permission will be 644, but when I execute

> chmod 777 test.sh

no error reports and `echo $?` also returns "0". But still `ls -l` shows permission as `644` and I can not execute it as `./test.sh`

Comment: Check your mount flags you are probably using the `noexec` mount option.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Yes, this can occur if your device is formatted with a filesystem that does not support that kind of permission setting, such as VFAT. In those cases, the umask is made up on the fly from a setting in the fstab (or the hotplugging equivalent).

See, most probably, man mount for details. For example, for VFAT, we find:

> *Mount options for fat*
>
> *uid=value and gid=value*
>
> Set the owner and group of all files.  (Default: the uid and gid of the current process.)
>
> *umask=value*
>
> Set the umask (the bitmask of the permissions that are not present). The default is the umask of the current
>                process.  The value is given in octal.

etc.

Comment: I couldn't get this as I am a newbie, would you mind elaborating more on `In those cases, the umask is made up on the fly from a setting in the fstab ...` I have to perform the same task as the OP.
Thanks in Advance...

Comment: @shekharsuman: it means you cannot chmod files on a VFAT mount. All files on a VFAT mount have the same permissions, and what those are is set in the line for the device in `/etc/fstab`. (I have no idea where it is set if you use automounters.)

Answer (score 4):

It looks like your filesystem is mounted with the `noexec` option, which forbids executing programs on that filesystem by acting as if all execution bits in permissions were unset. If you use the `user` mount option (or if some user interface uses it under the hood), `noexec` is turned on unless you explicitly turn it off with `exec`.

Most USB sticks use the MSDOS-derived VFAT filesystem, which has no notion of permissions. You can only specify permission bits when you mount the filesystem, and these permissions apply to all the files on that filesystem.

If you don't have permission to execute a script, call the interpreter explicitly:

```
sh /media/stick/test.sh
```

For a dynamically linked binary, invoke the dynamic linker.

```
/lib/ld-linux.so.2 /media/stick/myprog
```