# No permission on external drive

Tags: permissions, symlink, external-hdd

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [can't change file permission](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/41555/cant-change-file-permission)

On my hard drive everything is fine, but when I go onto my external drive I can't chmod. I get no error message but the changing simply doesn't take place.

I have tested it and it works fine when I'm on my laptops hard drive.

The same goes for creating symbolic links, I can create symbolic links on my hard drive but when I try to do it on my external drive I get:

`failed to create symbolic link, Operation not permitted`

What is the problem?

Comment: Check how you mounted it, I suspect it is read-only.

Comment: to core folder of the external drive is 700, and chmod doesn't work on that either.

Comment: Are you able to log in as the root? Also try using the sudo command. You haven't mentioned what OS you are using.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

What file system is on your external drive? Are you sure it supports concepts like owner, permissions and symbolic links? `FAT32`, for example, doesn't support these things, so you won't be able to use utilities like `chmod`, and Windows "shortcuts" are not the same as UNIX symlinks.

Comment: I don't know what file system it has, how do i get that information?

Comment: That depends on what OS you are using - but as a starting point, you can try `df -T` and `mount` - both should give the file system type.

Comment: my external drive is on the good old vfat system. is there any way to change that to ext4 without formatting?

Comment: Not that I am aware of - those two file systems are so vastly different, that I suspect the only way to change is to bite the bullet and reformat. Sorry to be the bearer of bad tidings.