# How to run Linux script in FAT (it is not working like on Linux' FS)

Tags: scripting, filesystems, fat

How to run Linux script e.g configure etc, in FAT (or alike raw) filesystem ?

```
$ sudo chmod -R 777 .
$ ./configure
bash: ./configure: Permission denied
```

How to solve ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming it is a shell script, manually passing it to the relevant binary should let you run it:

```
$ head -n 1 configure
#!/bin/bash
$ bash configure
```

FAT does not support individual file permissions. So you cannot assign one with `chmod`. Though, it should be possible to configure to [treat all files in a FAT as executable](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/308056/423679).

Answer (score 0):

You have to set the execute
permissions on the script path not the current directory path (.) :

```
sudo chmod 777 configure
```

Then execute it :

```
sh configure
```

Comment: You don't need to do `sh configure` to execute the script at that point - in fact, it only works if `configure` is a shell script (the OP only mentioned that it is a "script", not necessarily a "shell script" - e.g., if it's instead a Perl or Python script, running it with `sh` doesn't work).  In that case, just run `./configure` as the OP originally did, after fixing the permissions as you mentioned.

Comment: Yes thanks i see !